# Replace text in column in Pandas based on another column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to take the value in a column in `pandas` and remove that value from another column.  However - the `replace` behavior is not working the way I would have expected.

In this example, I am trying to make the value in col2 equal to 'something'

```
import pandas as pd  

#Build the dataframe
col1 = ['ABC', 'DEF']
col2 = ['something - ABC', 'something - DEF']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['ABC', 'DEF'], columns = ['col1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['something - ABC', 'something - DEF'], columns = ['col2'])
df = df1.join(df2, on=None, how='left')

#Replace ' - ABC' so column is just 'something'
df['newcolumn'] = df.col2.replace(' - '+df.col1, '')
```

This is returning the value that's already in col2.  What am I missing?

Comment: Will  the pattern always be `-` followed by something you want to replace? Furthermore, will this pattern always remain at the end?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ trying to make it so it complete removes the value of col1 from col2.  Strip in this case will remove it, but trying to match it specifically.

Comment: Afraid you're out of luck, replace doesn't work like that. The only thing you could do is get a list of all unique values and create a massive regex and call `str.replace`. Which I guarantee will be slow.

Comment: See my answer for details. You're also free to do timing comparisons yourself, you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str.rsplit`:

```
df['newcolumn'] = df.col2.str.rsplit('-', 1).str[0]
print(df)
  col1             col2  newcolumn
0  ABC  something - ABC  something
1  DEF  something - DEF  something
```

One big assumption here is that your pattern to remove succeeds the last hyphen in the string.

---

Another possibility using `str.replace` with regex.

```
df['newcolumn'] = df.col2.str.replace('-[^-]*$', '')
print(df)
  col1             col2  newcolumn
0  ABC  something - ABC  something
1  DEF  something - DEF  something
```

---

Yet another possibility, with `str.replace` would be to retrieve all unique values from `col1` and create a massive regex (more focused than the above approaches, but also much slower).

```
df['newcolumn'] = df.col2.str.replace(r'\s*\-\s*({})'.format('|'.join(vals)), '')
print(df)
  col1             col2  newcolumn
0  ABC  something - ABC  something
1  DEF  something - DEF  something
```

if `col1` has strings separated by space, you'll need to wrap each one inside their own parens, so use this:

```
df.col2.str.replace(r'\s*\-\s*(({}))'.format(')|('.join(vals)), '')
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `str.split`

```
df['newcolumn']=df.col2.str.split(' -',expand=True)[0]
df
Out[136]: 
  col1             col2   newcolumn
0  ABC  something - ABC   something 
1  DEF  something - DEF   something
```

Comment: Note that I used rsplit instead of split as I assume the pattern to remove comes after the last hyphen. Your code assumes the opposite (just thought you should make that clear).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace pattern based on column 1, this would work independently of the delimiter:

```
import pandas as pd  

#Build the dataframe
col1 = ['ABC', 'DEF']
col2 = ['something - ABC', 'something - DEF']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['ABC', 'DEF'], columns = ['col1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['something - ABC', 'something - DEF'], columns = ['col2'])
df = df1.join(df2, on=None, how='left')

#Replace ' - ABC' so column is just 'something'
df['newcolumn'] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x.col2).replace(' - ' + str(x.col1), '') ,axis = 1)
```